# How do I prevent to operate over an empty matrix or a matrix with empty columns or row?

Tags: matrix, prolog

In the problem that I want to solve a well defined matrix has no empty rows or columns.

For example the matrix `[[],[]]` is not valid.

When I call the function first_column, how do I prevent to execute it if the matrix that I send as an argument is not valid as defined before?

```
first_column([],[],[]).
first_column([[H|T]|Tail],[H|Col],[T|Rows]):- first_column(Tail,Col,Rows).
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically, what you're asking can be done by testing for an end-condition of a list with one element, rather than an empty list, based on the specs you gave.

```
first_column([[H|T]],[H],[T]).
first_column([[H|T]|Tail],[H|Col],[T|Rows]):- first_column(Tail,Col,Rows).
```

However, beyond your specs, I suspect that you'll also need to "transfer" your final Col,Rows to end variables, something like:

```
first_column([[H|T]],C,R,[H|C],[T|R]).
first_column([[H|T]|Tail],[H|C],[T|R],Col,Rows):- 
    first_column(Tail,C,R,Col,Rows).
```

The modified predicate would be called with initial conditions, like

```
first_column(List,[],[],Col,Rows).
```